# Algorithm for superdivide

Tags: java, c++

A int is superdivide if every digit in the number divides the number. Example `128` divides itself since `128` is divisible by `1, 2, and 8` superdivide number not divisible by `0`.

```
Sample Input #1

superDivide(184)

Sample Output #1

true

Sample Input #2

superDivide(39)

Sample Output #2

false

Sample Input #3

superDivide(120)

Sample Output #3

false
```

enter code here

```
public class SuperDivide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperDivide obj = new SuperDivide();
        boolean result = obj.checkSuper(1001);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public boolean checkSuper(int num){
        //write your code here
        int n1;
        int n2=num;
        if(num%10==0)
        return false;
        while(num>0){
            n1=num%10;
            if(n2%n1==0){
                num=num/10;
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;


    }
```

above code runs fine upto digit number but not for 3digit,any suggestion?

Comment: looks like your homework...

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the problem? Have you debugged through it yourself, and seen where the intermediate results aren't as you expected?

Comment: Your code returns true as soon as one digit divide big number... and loop forever for the first digit which don't divide the big number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your method should look like this :

```
public boolean checkSuper(int num) {
    int n1;
    int n2 = num;
    while(num > 0) {
        if(num % 10 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        n1 = num % 10;
        if(n2 % n1 == 0) {
            num = num / 10;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think this would work !

Comment: While this code may solve the asker's problem, it would be preferable to explain how it works and what are the differences between it and what the asker has tried.

Answer (score 1):

Some logical errors like divide by zero and wrong placement of return:

Here is the working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        SuperDivide obj = new SuperDivide();
        boolean result = obj.checkSuper(66);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public boolean checkSuper(int num) {
        //write your code here
        int n1;
        int n2 = num;

        while (num > 0) {
            n1 = num % 10;
            if (n1 == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (n2 % n1 == 0) {
                num = num / 10;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the best answer here, if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a number. Let's call it `num`. Obviously we need a `remaining` with we initialize with `num`. As we do NOT want to modify `num` at all, let's be nice and declare if `final`. This prevents us from accidentally changing it.

The last digit, let's call it `lastDigit` can be determined via remaining%10.

Now we test `if lastDigit == 0 or (num % lastDigit != 0)` -> `return false`

Otherwise, we go one step further by `remaining = remaining/10` and again test the last digit, until `remaining` = 0. So we could wrap the whole thing in a `while(remaining > 0)` loop.

What you are doing is slightly different, since you MODIFY your original `num` variable, which means that in the 2nd test you don't divide the original num by the value, but the modified one. Result? Don't know. Probably not really correct.